# How to uncover structure of a complex XML

Tags: xml

I have a large XML file that contains tons of nested tags. I want to know the structure of this XML. Something like hierarchy tree image, any other formats. What tools should use?

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, I wrote this in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open { $ARGV[0] } ;
my $count ;

def processNonRec $type $parent $node {
    my $name = $type ;
    perl { $name .= $count->{"*$type"}++ } ;
    echo :s '"' $parent '"' " -> " '"' $name '"' ;
    echo :s '"' $name '" [label="' $type '()"]' ;
}

def processNode $parent $node {
    my $label = name($node);
    my $name ;
    perl { $name = $label . "=" . $count->{$label}++ } ;
    echo :s '"' $parent '"' " -> " '"' $name '"' ;
    if $node/self::* {
        if (count($node/../*[name() = $label]) > 1) {
            my $num = count($node/preceding-sibling::*[name() = $label]) ;
            $label = concat($label, "[", $num + 1, "]") ;
        }
    } else {
        $label = concat("@", $label) ;
    }
    echo :s '"' $name '" [label="' $label '"]' ;
    for ($node/node() | $node/@*) {
        if self::*                         processNode $name (.) ;
        if (count(.|../@*) = count(../@*)) processNode $name (.) ;
        if self::text()                    processNonRec 'text'    $name (.) ;
        if self::comment()                 processNonRec 'comment' $name (.) ;
        if self::processing-instruction()  processNonRec 'pi'      $name (.) ;
    }
}

echo 'strict digraph' name() '{' ;
echo 'node [shape=box]' ;
processNode "document" /* ;
echo '}' ;
```

It outputs a .dot file used by [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org) to draw the graph.